# "Him" or "his" used with "resulted"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which sentence is more grammatically correct:

> Jack’s predilection toward competitive sports resulted in **him** becoming a great tennis player.

or

> Jack's predilection toward competitive sports resulted in **his** becoming a great tennis player.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for *his*, because *becoming* is a gerund and hence a noun. And we wouldn't say 'That is him house', would we.

Comment: On the other hand, the result we are talking about is "He became a great tennis player" If I showed you a picture of him practicing as he was honing his skills, I might say, "This is him becoming a great tennis player."

Comment: @Jim Quite so. Because in that example 'becoming' is not a gerund but a present participle forming part of an adjectival clause.

Comment: I think both are correct, and they are different in terms of what they emphasize. The first sentence puts the stress on 'him', and the second one on 'becoming'. For this concrete example the difference is not quite visible, but consider these: `I remember him becoming a great tennis player` and `I remember his becoming a great player`. The first version tells about the author remembering how good he was during that period, and the second - about the efforts he spent to become a great player. So to me, they are both correct.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. You may be right. But my response to Jim's comment stands.

Comment: @Jim There is an excellent answer under choster's link above to a former OP, confirming why, in your example, it has to be him (accusative), rather than 'his' (genetive).

Comment: @ArsenY.M. yes you are right. see the link by choster above to a former discussion, and the excellent answer from the formidable nohat.